# How to Code Unwrap across whole project in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I have this bit of code:

```
<div class="kt-portlet__head">
  <div class="kt-portlet__head">
    <div class="kt-portlet__head-label">
      <span class="kt-portlet__head-icon">
        <i class="la la-user"></i>
      </span>
      <h3 class="kt-portlet__head-title">
        Edit User
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The content changes across the project, ie, everything within the `div` with the class `kt-portlet__head-label`

I need to remove the duplicate wrapper div (i.e, you will see there are two `div` tags with class `kt-portlet__head`).

To my knowledge:

- I cannot do a search and replace because searching for just the two open wrapper tags and replacing with one will leave two `div` close tags instead of one.
- I cannot do a search and replace on the whole thing because the content changes as stipulated above
- I can use 'code wrap/unwrap' on an open document - but this is manual and i might as well just delete the two lines individually.

Isn't there a way to do a kind of 'code unwrap' + search and replace to get this achieved?

Comment: You generate this html content with PHP ? On this case, add your code here please.

Comment: no, its not generated - its static code across many files in a project

Comment: From what I can tell, I should be looking at "Search Structurally" / "Replace Structurally". Unfortunately the JetBrains web site is down for me and I am unable to view documentation on it...

Comment: here it is: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html